# how to zoom in an image without increasing its size?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to get a zoom effect on the image but without increasing its size on the screen, I was able to use "transform: scale ()" for the image to get a sort of zoom, but I do not want the space it occupies increases, which is what happens when I increase the scale ().

How can I get this? The current effect I've achieved is on my testing site and in the future will be a blog / portfolio: http://marcosroot.pythonanywhere.com/blog/

The effect happens with hover in the image.

PS: the code looks like this:

```
&__media {
    transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.025);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about some canvas magic? For example: https://codepen.io/techslides/pen/zowLd

Comment: @Miroslav this seems very complicated for my purpose, I want despite a zoom effect on a hover, but without increasing the space that the image occupies on the screen

Comment: hmm... maybe you could wrap it in a container that has overflow set to hidden?

Comment: @Jhecht it's the answer, you should add it I guess

Comment: @Jhecht exactly this, thx

Comment: in case Jhecht doesn't add the answer you can answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 10):

This approach has no dependencies and works in all modern browsers. `JavaScript` updates `CSS` variables through `setProperty` and the `background-position`of the zoomed image dynamically updates as you move your mouse.

[image]

```js
const zoomify = (width, height) => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.zoomify');
  el.style.width = `${width}px`;
  el.style.height = `${height}px`;
  el.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  const dimensions = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  const [x, y] = [
    e.clientX - dimensions.left,
    e.clientY - dimensions.top
  ];
  const [percentX, percentY] = [
    Math.round(100 / (dimensions.width / x)),
    Math.round(100 / (dimensions.height / y))
  ];
  this.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', percentX);
  this.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', percentY);
}

zoomify(320, 212);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.starting-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.zoomify {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoomify::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528763216729-fb67cba479db?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=728e3916b52b079634aa7c7f82af612d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=6774&q=80%206774w,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528763216729-fb67cba479db?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=728e3916b52b079634aa7c7f82af612d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=6774&q=80%206774w");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  will-change: background-position;
}

.zoomify:hover .starting-image {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.zoomify:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  background-size: 250%;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  background-position: calc(var(--mouse-x) * 1%) calc(var(--mouse-y) * 1%);
}
```

```html
<div class="zoomify">
  <img class="starting-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528763216729-fb67cba479db?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=728e3916b52b079634aa7c7f82af612d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=6774&q=80%206774w,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1528763216729-fb67cba479db?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=728e3916b52b079634aa7c7f82af612d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=6774&q=80%206774w" alt="diner">
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool, maybe I did not ask the question correctly, but my problem was solved thanks to @Jhecht, who said to put the image in a container with "overflow: hidden;"

Comment: @marcossouza Overkill, I guess. Sorry for misunderstanding what you needed.